# jquery's .html() method not working in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display a popup by fetching the html data using GET method and adding to a div using .html() method. below is the code I have written for the same. This is working fine in IE and Firefox but failing in Chrome and Safari.

```
function openPopupWindow(url, width) {
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'GET',
          timeout: 180000,
          success: function(data){
           var popUpBody = $("div.popupDivClass").html(data);
           $(popUpBody).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        width:width,                  
                        modal: true
                  });
           //$("div.ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
            $(popUpBody).dialog( "open" );
          }
      });
}
```

I am getting the below exception:

> Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 - jquery-1.4.4.min.js:122

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the HTML that you attempting to put into the popupbody?

Comment: It has the html code to display text,radio buttons,dropdowns and submit buttons. When I tried to alert 'data' its displaying the entire html content like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>; <body> <ui:define name="preIdContent" /><ui:define name="postIdContent"><h:panelGroup columnClasses="palletPopupstyle" >..

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove any reference on DOCTYPE. E.g. I had the same issue and I removed the following line and it worked like a charm:

```
<!doctype html public "*">
```

Comment: i have removed <!DOCTYPE html>   still itsa not working in safari...its working in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are selecting `$("div.popupDivClass")` which can be multiple element. and `html(data)` doesn't know what to return from array of elements. Try something like this

```
$("div.popupDivClass").each(function ()
    {
        $(this).html(data);
    })
```

Or try selecting by `id`

Note: However not guaranteed.

Comment: Still no luck.I have defined the popupDivClass div in parent html. In the data field I am getting the html content like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>  <body>
<form id="itemPopupForm" name="itemPopupForm" method="post" action="/enewitem/pages/createItemType.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"><input type="hidden" ..>
Do we need to define DOM traversal type based on browser?

Comment: @kkm could you define `id` instead.

Comment: You can set `.html()` on multiple selections. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9yttC/

Comment: @AlastairPitts it might and about opening multiple dialog ... i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The below two lines are causing the issue.
I removed the below lines from data string and its working fine in chrome and safari:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just to help others folks having problem with Chrome and possibly Safari. Its seems that Chrome is very seletive with the things that can be inserted using jquery.html().

I have discovered two cases when Chrome cries the **Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11** exception

- When inserting bad html. Like . Upss i forget to close the tag with an /. So `$('body').html("<button value='This is a button'>");` is going to give you Exception 11. The solution for this is easy, just insert valid XHTML.
- Try this in the chrome console `$('body').html("C&aacute;psula");` The ampersand is the problem there. My (almost) solution for this case is transforming the ampersand to Unicode like $('body').html("\u0026psula"); \u0026 is &. Note that ampersand is not the only symbols that battle against chrome.

Maybe the page encoding have something to do with this.

So your problem is your data variable that return your Ajax